# UITableView: Why is the "number of rows" not being updated after a delete?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

Here is my code, which is supposed to delete the selected row.  It is causing the app to crash because it claims the number of rows is not correct.  I checked and it is not correct; the row in the table has been deleted, but apparently the number of rows has not been updated (the code does get hit)... how is this possible? (I have another UITableViewController with the exact code, which works).  How do I fix it?

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    //  remove row from the table
    SQLite *sql = [[SQLite alloc] init];
    [sql deleteReadingsRow: indexPath.row];

    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Here is the code that determines the number of rows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    SingletonListOfReadings  *rShareInstance = [SingletonListOfReadings sharedInstance];

    return rShareInstance.listOfReadings.count; // Return the number of rows in the section
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... I was relying on a singleton (SingletonListOfReadings) which was not being reset when the row was deleted in the d/b table.

Answer (score 0):

While you found your issue, you should look into using [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.  With little work, it can automatically update your table when rows are added, deleted, or modified.  Its a more reliable solution in general than depending on keeping singletons synchronized.  There are a lot of examples of using it with tables.